# how to convert array of objects to key value pairs in php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object, keyvaluepair

I have an array of objects and I need to convert to key value pairs, my code is

i have a model as:
model setting.php

```
public function currency_info(){
     $currency_info = [
                ['code' => 'AED', 'name' => 'United Arab Emirates Dirham'],
                ['code' => 'ANG', 'name' => 'NL Antillian Guilder'],
                ['code' => 'ARS', 'name' => 'Argentine Peso'],
                ['code' => 'AUD', 'name' => 'Australian Dollar'],
                ['code' => 'BRL', 'name' => 'Brazilian Real'],
              ]
}
```

and controller as:

SettingController.php

```
public function index()
{
        $setting = new Setting();
        $currency_list = $setting->currency_info();

        $result = [];
        foreach ($currency_list as $currency) {
            $result[$currency->code] = $currency->name;
        }

        return $result;
}
```

i get the following error:

> ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Trying to get property 'code' of non-object

Where am I doing wrong and how can I correct this?

Comment: Laravel has built in method to convert into array just use `$setting->currency_info()->toArray();`

Comment: this doesnot work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the data your trying to iterate over is an array (from an object) the notation should be...

```
$result[$currency['code']] = $currency['name'];
```

Or if you want a shorter version (depends on version of PHP), use [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)...

```
$result = array_column($currency_list, 'name', 'code');
```

Comment: $result[$currency['code']] = $currency['name'];  works great, thank you for your answer

Comment: this is the best answer

Comment: It's annoying at times as people will downvote and not leave feedback.  It's just something you will unfortunately have to get used to.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($currency_info as $currency) {
    $result[$currency['code']] = $currency['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`currency_info` function  return array, so treat it as array. You are using `$currency->code` to access `code` key from array, use as `$currency["code"]` instead.

```
public function index() {
    $setting = new Setting();
    $currency_list = $setting->currency_info();

    $result = [];
    foreach ($currency_list as $currency) {
        $result[$currency["code"]] = $currency["name"];
    }
    return $result;
}
```